# Singular/Plural verb in Appositive

Tags: verbal-noun

> Many of blues great Bessie Smith’s songs describe the experiences of
>   southern Black migrants, especially **the struggles of Black women** to
>   adjust to urban life in the northern United States.

In the appositive '*the struggles of black women*' why do we write 'struggles' not 'struggle' for describing 'black **women**' which is plural? Why is using a singular verb with a plural subject right here?

Comment: I'm not sure that "the struggles of black women" is an appositive. And **the struggles** is not a verb, but a noun, a plural noun.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, could you please explain how did you verify 'the struggles' to be noun? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Many of blues great Bessie Smith’s songs describe the experiences of southern Black migrants, especially the **struggles** of Black women to adjust to urban life in the northern United States.

The word **struggles** is a "[verbal noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun)":
 1. It is preceded by the definite article (**the** struggles).
 2. It has no subject, either overt or implied. (For instance, "**He** struggles", "**Jack** struggles")
 3. It parallels the word **the experiences** - which is clearly a noun, a plural noun:

> The songs describe **the experiences** and **the struggles** of Black folk. (both **the experiences** and **the struggles** are objects of the verb "describe")

4. It is modified by an **of-phrase**, like a noun would be.

> What kind of struggles? The struggles **of Black women**.